# How to build treeviewer from an XML file without AJAX

Tags: javascript, jstree

I need to build a treeview from an XML file. I don't want to use AJAX, as I can simply read the file from my disk (I'm building this app on Electron)

fs.readFile('./xmlfile.xml', function(err, data) {};

Is there anyone that could guide me how to build a tree of an custom made XML file? Basically I'd like to be able to build a tree from any XML data I put into my file.

I've already tried using JStree, but I keep having the same issue with it - it doesn't spit any errors in the console and prints a blank page.

testData is where keep my xmlfile.xml (file is definetely valid and it prints correctly when I put it through console log)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// NeDB - Database init
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./xmlfile.xml', function(err, testData) {

$('#cRIO_tree')
      .jstree({
        "core": {
          "animation": 0,
          "check_callback": true,
          "icon": "../assets/tree.png",
          "themes": {
            "stripes": true
          },
          "xml_data": {
            "data": testData,
            "progressive_render": "true"
          },
        },
        "dnd": {
          "always_copy": true
        },
        "types": {
          "#": {
            "max_children": 1,
            "max_depth": 10,
            "valid_children": ["root"]
          },
          "root": {
            "valid_children": ["default"]
          },
          "default": {
            "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous",
            "valid_children": ["default", "file"]
          },
          "file": {
            "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-flash",
            "valid_children": []
          }
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", 
         "sort", "wholerow", "themes", "xml_data"]
      })
     }
    }
```

Problem is that no matter what I put into my xml - it simply doesn't print it. I even tried examples from

https://old.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data

```
    <!-- FLAT -->
    <root>
       <item id="root_1" parent_id="0" state="closed">
         <content>
           <name><![CDATA[Node 1]]></name>
         </content>
       </item>
      <item id="node_2" parent_id="root_1">
        <content>
          <name><![CDATA[Node 2]]></name>
        </content>
      </item>
    </root>
```

and that doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: So where is `testData` coming from here exactly? You've missed out the most crucial part of the code. You've described it and claim it's "working", but since you're asking, we'd have to assume there might be a problem. Therefore it makes sense to actually show how you load it, in full. As a pure guess, perhaps you are not waiting for the file to finish loading before referring to the data in your tree? File loading is an async operation.

Comment: @ADyson fair point, added more code, sorry for lack of information, I'm still learning how to ask questions properly.

Comment: No problem. The best thing to remember is that a) we read see your screen or your disk (or your mind!) and b) a description of your code is never a substitute for the actual code :-)

Comment: ok so looks like you are basically using the code correctly. Next thing then would be to see a sample of the XML and see if it's what's expected by JSTree (I'm no expert on that but I'm sure someone will be interested)

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your comments, I've added a sample - and as mentioneed above - it doesn't matter what I put into an XML file, JStree doesn't really want to coop with it.. I have to say that I've been looking for an anserw for quite long time now and no one tried to do it this way, so I'm starting to doubt if it's even possible..

Comment: I notice that XML documentation comes from an old version of the JSTree website. The new version of the site does not mention XML at all. Which version of JSTree are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535253/populating-jstree-from-xml-string suggests that support for XML was dropped in later versions, so (unless you are using an old version where that XML plugin actually works), you could either switch to using JSON, or maybe use the code in the answer there to help you convert XML to JSON